# How to merge Flux stream of tables into one table?

Tags: influxdb, flux

I'm relatively new in Flux and still learning but now can't figure out how to transform stream of tables into single table.

Here is my use case:
I have messages coming from IoT devices. I populate stats bucket with information how many messages came from anchor with the payload. Now I want to do some aggregation and visualize how many messages came though each anchor in a last minute etc. So I run this query:

```
from(bucket: "MessageStats")
  |> range(start: -1m)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "allMessages")
  |> sum()
  |> pivot(rowKey: ["anchor"], columnKey: ["_field"], valueColumn: "_value")
  |> keep(columns: ["anchor", "anchorVersion", "allMessages"])
```

I get this result

| table | allMessages | anchor | anchorVersion |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 98 | 304511F94F8D | 2.2.0 |
| 1 | 10 | 304511F95396 | 2.2.0 |
| 2 | 79 | 3403DE2C5BD0 | 2.2.0 |
| 3 | 56 | 587A621B0317 | 2.2.0 |
| 4 | 65 | 78DB2FB9CB6B | 2.2.0 |
| 5 | 40 | 78DB2FCA4466 | 2.2.0 |
| 6 | 16404 | AC233FC0F64A | Minew |
| 7 | 12205 | AC233FC0F67F | Minew |
| 8 | 16269 | AC233FC0F689 | Minew |
| 9 | 12888 | AC233FC0F68B | Minew |
| 10 | 15919 | AC233FC0F68D | Minew |
| 11 | 26 | E415F64DF643 | 2.2.0 |

But all this is still a stream of tables... so my question is how to transform it into a single table in order to get properly visualized on a dashboard?

Now I see it as
[image]

Any help to point me to the right direction would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can add a group with no parameters to your query:

```
from(bucket: "MessageStats")
  |> range(start: -1m)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "allMessages")
  |> sum()
  |> pivot(rowKey: ["anchor"], columnKey: ["_field"], valueColumn: "_value")
  |> keep(columns: ["anchor", "anchorVersion", "allMessages"])
  |> group()
```